# Is there a way to enable sound via HDMI on my TV Monitor from the MacBook Pro late 2010 (OSX 10.8.3)?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, hdmi

When connecting my MacBook Pro Late 2010 to my Samsung TV Monitor via HDMI there is no sound coming out, only picture. Alternatively when I'm using my dual-boot Windows 7 installed on the same machine the sound works as it should via HDMI on my TV monitor.

I have tried everything and have concluded that it's a built-in option that is not available in this version of the MacBook Pro Late 2010 (7,1).

Is there a way to fix this issue without needing to buy additional hardware?

Answer (score 1):

**Method 1:**

<kbd>Option</kbd>-<kbd>click</kbd> on the volume icon on the right side of the menu bar, and source control should show up.

[image]

**Method 2:**(@NevinWilliams also mentioned this method)

Open Audio MIDI Setup using spotlight or find it in the Applications folder(`/Applications/Utilities/Audio\ MIDI\ Setup.app` for me).[image]

**Method 3:**

Open System Preferences and click on sound in the second row. Make sure 'Output' is selected at the top. Then chose the name of the TV in the white box.[image]

Answer (score 0):

Using "Audio MIDI Setup.app" in the /Applications/Utilities/ folder, under the Window menu, select "Show Audio Window".

This will give you a list of input and output devices.

I have  `HDMI -- 0 in/2 out` listed on the left, in addition to `Built-in Input` and `Built-in Output`.  There may be other I/O devices listed, depending on your configuration.  To the right of the device names, ought to be 3 icons:  a Mac face (for system sounds), a speaker icon (for main sounds) and a microphone icon (for input).  These icons will be placed beside the audio device to which they're currently assigned; my guess would be the 'Built-in' devices.

Select HDMI then right-click.  A menu should then appear giving you the options to `use this device for sound output` and `play alerts and sound effects through this device`.  Select the options options you wish, and test.   See the utility's help file for further information.

Update:  I learned the Macbook in question has a mini DisplayPort connection.  I then found a link to a [Griffin Mini DisplayPort to HDMI w/ Audio](http://store.apple.com/ca/product/TY600VC/A/griffin-mini-displayport-to-hdmi-with-audio-dvi) on the Apple Store which specifically says it works with the mid-2010 13" Macbook Pros.

Comment: Ok Nevin this is the first thing I did ofc!In my I/O devices HDMI is not(never) listed also i can't install it.This issue is more complex than it seems...

Comment: I've noticed in the documentation on our new Philips LCD that the 3 HDMI inputs are not equivalent, and it recommends attaching a computer to port 1;  Might it be as simple as that?   
I've just looked up your model on MacTracker; it lists for 'Displays' 1 - Mini DisplayPort (VGA, DVI, or dual-link DVI with adapter).  I'll have to research a bit, as it's not a native HDMI interface.  (my 1st gen mini didn't do sound via its DVI-HDMI cable.)

Comment: Original post updated.